# JQuery tabs destroy() not working in jquery-ui-1.10.0

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am trying to upgrade from jquery-ui-1.8.23 to jquery-ui-1.10.0.

Suddenly **$("#tabs").destroy();** does not work any more.

I have read the ui upgrade guide found here:

http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#tabs

"Tabs now uses ui-tabs-destroy instead of destroy.tabs." 
I don't know how this code would look like and there are no samples available.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Syntax for jQuery UI methods is incorrect. Methods should be passed to plugin as a string as documented in API

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "destroy" );
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/ngDP3/

API reference ( with example code): http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-destroy

> Tabs now uses ui-tabs-destroy instead of destroy.tabs

This is for internal data useage within plugin and really has no bearing on using method

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however it still does not work:
      
TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$( "#tabs" ).tabs("destroy");

Comment: `$(...).tabs is not a function` means either you haven't included jQueryUI.js, or included before jQuery.js, or have multiple versions of jQuery.js being loaded in page or forgot to load jQuery.js, or path to file(s) are incorrect

Comment: Here are all my js includes, perhaps one of them is the problem:

jquery-1.9.0.js
jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js
jquery.dataTables.min.js
jquery.bpopup-0.8.0.min.js
jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js
fnReloadAjax.js
jquery.contextmenu.js
jquery.treeview.js
colResizable-1.3.min.js
ZeroClipboard.js

Comment: look in browser console to see if they are all loading and only one copy of jQuery.js in page

Comment: I cannot see any duplicates and they are all loading ok. It was working ok until I switched version of jQuery and Jquery UI.

Comment: I am an idiot... tabs was missing in the version of jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js I had. I downloaded the "full" version of ui, and now it works! I am quite sure that I had selected tabs when downloading the version that didn't work, I just didn't check if tabs actually were in the file.

Comment: ahhh.. the only option i forgot to mention... I always use full version from CDN